# Setting names of new calculated variables and assign values using a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, rlang

I am writing a function, which is using references from two data sets (RawDataSplit and Hierarchy). All these datasets are connected. I need to summarise the data based on a function that will be applied to all the selected columns. I am using `summarise_` to do this.

I have created a function which will be used to summarise the columns per_qid, this is to calculate percentage for each column.

Then I am creating a function with three arguments: `fav_fun(dataset,levelname,demo_var)`

dataset is for the data on which we need aggregations, in this case it is RawDataSplit

levelname is one of the column in  RawDataSplit by which data would be grouped

demo_var would be one of the variable chosen from data set 'Hierarchy', this would be one of the demographic variable like Age.

Function for aggregation:

```
per_qid<-function(x){
  counts<-sum(ifelse(x==4|x==5,1,0),na.rm=TRUE
  total<-sum(ifelse(x==1|x==2|x==3|x==4|x==5,1,0),na.rm=TRUE)
  #Masking and rounding
  x<- ifelse(total<masking_criteria,NA,roundUp(counts*100/total)) )
  x 
}
```

Function to aggregate RawDataSplit file:

```
fav_fun<-function(dataset,levelname,demo_var){  
  demo_var<- enquo(demo_var)
  levelname<-enquo(levelname)
  demographic<-Hierarchy[,demo_var]
  demo<-levels(demographic)
  summ_method<- paste('per_qid(',questions,')')
  summ_name<-paste0(questions,'_',demographic)
  fav <- dataset %>%
           group_by(!!levelname) %>%
           filter(status=="Complete") %>%
           filter(!!demo_var==demo[1]) %>% 
           summarise_(.dots = setNames,(summ_method,summ_name))
  fav
}
```

this fav_fun is throwing different kind of errors sometimes for `summarise_` and sometimes for other variables. Maybe something is wrong with the quoting and enquoting of variable also.

The sample data for these datasets are:
RawDataSplit:

```
structure(list(QID_1 = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L), QID_2 = c(4L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L), QID_3 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L), mastercode_1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mastercode_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "BROLLAND", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00372498>)
```

questions:

```
c("QID_1", "QID_10", "QID_11")
```

Hierarchy : (for now I have included one column only which is Age, I need to use it as demo_var in the function)

```
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, NA, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 
NA, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 
3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
NA, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
2L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 5L, 3L, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, NA, NA, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, NA, 
NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 5L, NA, NA, 3L, 
3L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 5L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 
NA, 4L, 2L, 4L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 4L, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 4L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 
4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 
4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 
NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 
1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, NA, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
NA, NA, NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
NA, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, NA, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, 4L, 
NA, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, NA, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 
4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 
2L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, NA, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 
4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 4L, NA, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 
5L, 3L, 4L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 5L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 
4L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 
NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 
3L, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 
3L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, 5L, 5L, NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
4L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, 
NA, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 
NA, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 5L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 
NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 5L, 2L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, NA, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 
3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 
NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, NA, 5L, NA, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, NA, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
NA, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA),
.Label = c("18 to less than 25 years old", "25 to less than 35 years old", 

"35 to less than 45 years old", "45 to less than 55 years old",
"More than 55 years old"), class = "factor")
```

I need a function fav_fun which takes these three arguments and aggregates the RawDataSplit and modifies names too. Like for QID_1 the new name after aggregation would be QID_1_45 to less than 55 years old for level 1 of Age variable

function will be called as: fav_fun(RawDataSplit,mastercode_2,Age)

Comment: How you are calling the function

Comment: the dput output showed is a `factor` `vector`

Comment: Objects `questions` and `masking_criteria` are not defined.

Comment: Seems like you have multiple typos. In your first function, you have a missing `)` at the end of your first `sum`—looks like it got moved to the end of the line defining `x`. `setNames,(summ_method,summ_name)` is probably a stray comma. Also `summarise_` is deprecated in favor of the type of tidyeval you're doing elsewhere here—you're kind of mixing different approaches

Comment: I am calling the function as: fav_fun(RawDataSplit,mastercode_2,Age)

Comment: masking_criteria can be any value from 0 to 5, we have to specify this in the beginning. for this particular example we are taking this as 5

Comment: I also tried summarise instead of summarise_ but could not find a right way to assign formula for values and formula to column names also. If you have a better idea to do this please let me know.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Besides the typo problems pointed out by @camille, the `filter()`s don't make sense. The first is `filter(status=="Complete")`, but there is no `status` column in  `RawDataSplit`. Likewise, the second filter seems to use `demo_var`, which is set to `Age`. Yet, once again, there is no `Age` column in `RawDataSplit`.